# Joomla - show full text of only leading articles in Category Blog Layout

Tags: joomla, article

How can I show the full text of a leading article (even if it contains a read more) on a Category Blog Layout?

Is there a back-end setting I can change or which PHP file do I need to overwrite? I only want the leading article's fulltext to show, intro articles should still display the readmore with only intro text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't specify which version of Joomla! so this reply is based on 2.5.x

You will need to create a [layout override](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6) for `com_content`, specifically for the `category` view tmpl file `blog.php` or `blog_item.php`.

If your template already has an override installed for `com_content` you will find it at this location:

```
/templates/your-template/html/com_content/category/
```

If not you can copy the original files from your Joomla! 2.5's `component` directory at `/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/`

In that directory you will find a series of files starting with `blog` and ending with `.php` - you can override 1 or all of these by coping them to the first path listed above. *N.B. Only copy the files you need to change Joomla! is smart enough to look in the default directory if it doesn't find a version in the overrides location.*

The default Joomla! 2.5 installation has these blog files:

```
blog_children.php
blog_item.php
blog_links.php
blog.php
```

Basically `blog.php` is the main file and it includes the sub-layouts like `blog_item.php` as required.

If you're working from the default Joomla! 2.5 files, to achieve your goal you will probably have to override `blog.php` and `blog_item.php` and find a way to check whether you are in the leading item. Once you know that your in a leading item you will then want to echo out the full text of the item.

`blog_item.php` normally just outputs the intro text with a line like this:

`<?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>`

You'll want to have the full text echo'd so after you've wrapped the line above in an `if` to check if you're doing the leading item your output line will look something like this:

`<?php echo $this->item->introtext.$this->item->fulltext; ?>`

<s>***Note:*** I've haven't check this works it's just speculation and relies on the `$item` having the full row from the `#__content` table.</s>

So the articles full text isn't added to the article item in a standard install i.e. you can simply **echo** `$this->item->fulltext`.

There are two ways to get the full text.

The simplest & first is to modify the core file at `/components/com_content/models/articles.php` starting with the first `$query->select()` in the `function getListQuery()` which starts on/near **line 153**. Add ' a.fulltext,' after the **a.introtext** and before the single apostrophe, so the line looks like this:

```
function getListQuery()
{
    // Create a new query object.
    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Select the required fields from the table.
    $query->select(
        $this->getState(
            'list.select',
            'a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.title_alias, a.introtext, a.fulltext, ' .
            'a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, ' .
```

The second way, and the Joomla! update proof way (& therefore probably the better way) is to load the entire article in the override (ugly but it's not a hack) and concatenate the `fulltext` to the `introtext` of the first article.

To do this you simply use `getTable` to load the article using the $this->item->id in `blog.php` for the first leading item, so at about line 54, between the `<?php` and the `$this->item = &$item;` put:

```
if($leadingcount == 0) {
    $contentTable = JTable::getInstance('Content');
    if($contentTable->load($item->id)) {
        $item->introtext .= $contentTable->fulltext;
    }
}
```

*N.B. The if just limits it to the first leading article, if you remove the if it will attach the full text for all leading articles.*

This works on my dev installation of Joomla! 2.5.6 so you should be able to do it as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, and yes, it is indeed for J!2.5.

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems `$this->item->fulltext` is not available for a category blog layout. And I have no idea how to force it to load from the db.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added your second solution to my `blog.php` override and added `$this->item->leading = true;` in as well just before `echo $this->loadTemplate('item');` so as to test for it in `blog_item.php` and in the latter I test for `$this->item->leading` equal to true, and then change the readmore text to "LINK" like so: `echo ($this->item->leading ? "LINK" : JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE_TITLE'));`. Is this correct Joomla term?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can just use `JText::_()` rather than the `sprintf` version. You only need to use the `sprintf` version if you're inserting variables into the string.

Comment: That's what I did, the `sprintf` is a core Joomla function, I just added `"LINK"` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the two answers above, there are three changes required to blog.php and blog_item.php. This works in Joomla 3.1 The best is to copy these files to the template override

copy **blog.php** and **blog_item.php**

from **components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/**

to **[my template]/html/com_content/category/**

In **blog.php** in the loop for the leading items add one single line:

```
  <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
   <div class="leading-<?php echo ...?>">
                <?php
                    $this->item = &$item;
                    $this->item->leadingItem = true; //ADD THIS LINE !!!
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php
               $leadingcount++;
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the **blog_item.php** replace **"echo $this->item->introtext;"** with

```
if ($this->item->leadingItem){
//this is a leading article - show full text and remove "Read more..." button
        $itemID =  $this->item->id;
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT `fulltext` FROM `#__content` WHERE `id` =" . $itemID;
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $fulltext = $db->loadResult();
        echo $this->item->introtext . $fulltext; 

    }else{

        echo $this->item->introtext; 
}
```

Finally in the **blog_item.php** do not to show the *"Read more..."* button at the bottom of each article

Edit line

> if ($params->get('show_readmore') && $this->item->readmore)

into

> if ($params->get('show_readmore') && $this->item->readmore &&
>   !$this->item->leadingItem)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 2.5.x, in your template blog_item.php:

```
$itemID =  $this->item->id;
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "
SELECT `fulltext` 
FROM `#__content` 
WHERE `id` = $itemID;
";
$db->setQuery($query);
$fulltext = $db->loadResult();
```

and you can use the $fulltext string variable.